# decomposing a fraction into partial fractions

Tags: calculus

could someone please help me to decompose the following fraction into partial fractions?

$$\frac{1}{(a-x)(b-x)^{1/2}}$$

where a and b are just constants.

Thanks

Comment: Is this interpretation of your formula correct? Please edit yourself if not.

Comment: Yes that's correct, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Usually, a partial fraction decomposition is only possible for rational functions. The square root inside the denominator would prevent this kind of decomposition. In

$$\frac{a-b}{(x-a)\sqrt{x-b}}=\sqrt{x-b}\frac{(x-b)-(x-a)}{(x-a)(x-b)}$$

for $x>b$ one can decompose the second factor, but the square root remains.

Answer (score 1):

Partial fractions is a technique we use with *rational functions*, that is, ratios of polynomials. Your function is not a rational function.

However, if you are trying to integrate your function, as the tag calculus hints at, we can make the substitution $u^2=b-x$. So $dx=-2u\,du$. Also, $a-x=u^2-b+a$. So we want the following integral:
$$\int \frac{-2u}{(u^2-b+a)u}\,du.$$
The $u$ cancel, and we end up with an integral of shape
$$\int \frac{2}{b-a-u^2}.$$
If $b-a$ is negative, the integral is an $\arctan$. If $b-a$ is positive, we can factor $b-a-u^2$ and then use partial fractions.

Comment: Great, that's really helpful, thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome.